# Share Facebook settings

Tags: facebook, feed, sharethis

i have a litle e-commerce, when i share one product on facebook using shareThis i see a reference link of page society6 company like this: 
[image]

I don't know why, how can i disable it?

inspecting the code it seems be a feed?

[image]

After 3 days of struggle, I turn to you hoping to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

That is the app name, just change it if you want there to be something different. Or use sharer.php instead, it does not use an App. If you don´t have any control over the App, you need to forget about shareThis and use your own sharing function: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog